# Maven module project - how can I turn this into a library?

Tags: maven

Let's say I have

```
<parent>
  <module-prj-1>
  <module-prj-2>
  <module-prj-3>
```

Hypothetically, module-prj-1 is a project which is under development, but it is also a requirement for module-prj-2 and module-prj-3.

Let's say that the users of module-prj-2 aren't authorized to see the code of module-prj-1, but they require it as a dependency. Is there any way I can deploy module-prj-1 to my archiva repo as a library, so module-prj-2 and module-prj-3 users can still develop, without seeing the code of module-prj-1?

Still trying to figure this maven thing out .... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want that users of module-prj-2 see the code of module-prj-1, you should consider not using modules.

Define three distinct projects and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are attaching the source your "jar" artifacts are deployed as a libraries only.